# Chrome reroutes me automatically to servisepagefind.com and Bing without my consent -- how to stop it?

Tags: google-chrome, malware, search-engine

The way to replicate this is simple in my Chrome browser:

1. Type the search in Google
2. Modify the search in Google a second time
3. Then it sends me either to Bing or to this weird `servisepagefind.com`

What is going on? How do I stop this? How do I check for viruses in my computer?

Screenshots attached

1. `servisepagefind.com`
   [image]
2. Bing
   [image]

---

Cross-posted to Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/x1rqxl/chrome_reroutes_me_automatically_to/

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was a Chrome extension.

I fixed the issue by removing as many extensions as possible, especially the ones I didn't use or recognize, as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2Zb5qS1S9g.

To prevent this from happening to others, if you are able to identify the evil extension, I'd suggest that you report it.